# Chrome with kiosk mode + no print preview

Tags: google-chrome, printing

Is it possible to have a silent print without page preview? If so, how? I don't care to write an extension if possible, but I can't afford to try and weeks later discover that is not possible.

Why I need it? Explanation bellow:

I have kiosk computers that prints custom tickets with the name of the buyer.

The kiosk is a rented computer that I have no access to the S.O., and the S.O. can change from Windows, to Linux or any other, thats why it is a web application, but I can ask the renter to put some commands in launch options, so I tryed to use the "--kiosk --kiosk-printing" and the application prints without problem, except one: preview page pop up.

When I add the "--disable-print-preview" the ticket stop to go directly to print and show printer selection.

The process should be automatic, once the user entry his code (received from security channel), the kiosk should print the ticket without any interaction.

While ticket is been printed, a movie pass on kiosk explaing how to use the ticket in the gate, so when the pop up preview page appear, the user lost some information and need assistence, which broke the concept of automatic and fast service.

Comment: Have you found a solution to this? Thank you

Comment: I see there is still no "easy" solution for this problem?

Comment: I'm not working with that anymore, but if I'm not wrong, I changed to Firefox, but I don't know if that's possible in current version